# In Android: Are there limitations on what application is capable of doing when the phone rings?

Tags: android, camera, microphone

Is appliction able to open camera? Is it able to open bluetooth? Is it able to open microphone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check up on the receiver. When call received the receiver fires the intent or something if I am not mistaken , so you need to import the i.telephony , so that you can check the phone state , it will allow you to override the function when ever your phone is going to call  or receiving call.

Answer (score -1):

```
PackageManager.checkPermission(String permName, String pkgName);
```

I think this get the permissions info of app. Use package name and permission name.